# How to get the current, undistorted, wallpaper in Android?

Tags: java, android, wallpaper, android-wallpaper

I need to have access to the current cropped wallpaper (as a drawable or a bitmap) in order to blur some part of it and set these blurred parts as backgrounds for different views.

In Android, it is possible to get the current wallpaper as a drawable by calling `WallpaperManger.getDrawable()`. However, this method returns the complete drawable, that is often cropped by the user. The result is that when using this drawable, the wallpaper is distorted and cannot be used as a background for a view and be blurred since there is no way to "undistort it".

An alternative would be to set the activity as transparent and setting `windowShowWallpaper` to `true`. The problem with this approach is that the wallpaper cannot be accessed. Calling `getWindow().getDecorView().getBackground()` returns nothing as there is no background. The activity is just transparent and shows the wallpaper behind it.